# RippleDrawable as a background of View inside LinearLayout gets clipped by LinearLayout bounds - can this behavior be disabled?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, rippledrawable

So, I've a layout hierarchy like this:

```
LinearLayout
|-TextView
```

**TextView** has unbound RippleDrawable(i.e. with no mask) set as a background, however, it gets clipped by LinearLayout that contains this TextView. Are there any methods to alter this behavior, so RippleDrawable will not be clipped by LinearLayout?

Comment: Change its background to null or transparent

Comment: Hi, Dave, could you post your comment as an answer so I'll be able to mark it as a correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change its background to null or transparent `android:background="null"` or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`